# Azure storage table connector issue in LogicApp

Tags: azure-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am using logic app to process entities that are stored in Azure Storage table. Total number of entities are around 5000. If It use GetEntities action, it returns only 658 entities. Any clue why all entities are returned?

Comment: May be due to the [throttling limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuretables/#throttling-limits) of the table storage connector?

Comment: Do you have to process them in batch (all 5000)?  Such is rarely the best approach.

Comment: Based on my test, I can get all of the records (1000+ records). Please make sure that you logic app is not up to [throughput limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#throughput-limits). If it is that you could contact the [Logic Apps team](mailto:logicappsemail@microsoft.com) for help with your requirements.
)